# how to set wxPython main frame bottom right on screen?

Tags: python, wxpython

For better description,

```
+-----------------------+
|   Desktop (screen)    |
|                       |
|                       |
|         +----------+  |
|         | wxPython |  |
|         |   App.   |  |
|         |          |  |
|         |          |  |
|         +----------+  |
+-----------------------+
```

Look at **WxPython App.**, which is align to the bottom right of screen. How to I position my main frame because screen width is different on each pc?

For Better Understanding, I want to pop-up small window like [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/) and [FeedNotifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/) use!
i think both use python!!

Comment: Here's something that may be useful: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/ToasterBox.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use wx.DisplaySize to get display screen size, and from window.GetSize() you can get the size of your window which you want to position, these two informations are enough to pos it correctly. e.g. in this example I position a MinFrame it at bottom-right

```
import wx

def alignToBottomRight(win):
    dw, dh = wx.DisplaySize()
    w, h = win.GetSize()
    x = dw - w
    y = dh - h
    win.SetPosition((x, y))

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = wx.MiniFrame(None, title="My PopUp", size=(200,300), style=wx.DEFAULT_MINIFRAME_STYLE|wx.CLOSE_BOX)
alignToBottomRight(frame)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, just want to know wx.DisplaySize.
Are you from india?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid covering the taskbar you can use

`junk, junk, dw, dh = wx.ClientDisplayRect()`

instead of

`dw, dh = wx.DisplaySize()`

Solution code:

```
import wx

def alignToBottomRight(win):
    junk, junk, dw, dh = wx.ClientDisplayRect()
    w, h = win.GetSize()
    x = dw - w
    y = dh - h
    win.SetPosition((x, y))

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = wx.MiniFrame(None, title="My PopUp", size=(200,300), style=wx.DEFAULT_MINIFRAME_STYLE|wx.CLOSE_BOX)
alignToBottomRight(frame)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```